# OutOfMemoryError in okhttp3 large file downloading

Tags: android, rx-java, okhttp

I'm try to download zip file (size 160 Mb) via okhttp3. After a couple seconds app crash with stack:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
>                                                                at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:59)
>                                                                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
>                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                             Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8204 byte allocation with 1688 free bytes and 1688B until OOM
>                                                                at okio.Segment.(Segment.java:61)
>                                                                at okio.SegmentPool.take(SegmentPool.java:46)
>                                                                at okio.Buffer.writableSegment(Buffer.java:1151)
>                                                                at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
>                                                                at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:238)
>                                                                at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
>                                                                at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:377)
>                                                                at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:66)
>                                                                at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:238)
>                                                                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>                                                                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
>                                                                at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
>                                                                at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
>                                                                at com.bvs.data.MapService$2.call(MapService.java:102)
>                                                                at com.bvs.data.MapService$2.call(MapService.java:94)
>                                                                at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)

Here is my code:

```
Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<ResponseBody>) subscriber -> {
        Timber.e("Start zip loading");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(Tweakables.DEV_API_ENDPOINT + "files/" + Tweakables.MAP_ZIP)
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute(); // Crash appeared at this line 
            subscriber.onNext(response.body());
            response.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Use download manager to download large files like zip.

Comment: It may be that the `HttpLoggingInterceptor` tries to log the response body and thus load it's content in memory.

Comment: @miensol I have tried to set `HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE` same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe will be helpful for someone. Solved problem by using `Retrofit` annotation `Streaming`

```
@Streaming
@GET("files/"+Tweakables.MAP_ZIP)
Call<ResponseBody> downloadMap();
```